# A word for "nice welcome"

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for a word.

When we want to say that

> The new technology will recieve/has recieved a nice welcome from the
>   industrial companies.

what is a better word instead "nice welcome"

Comment: Do you intend to say that the new technology will recieve/recieved a nice welcome from the industrial companies? The sentence that you have posted is not very coherent.

Comment: @Vaibhav thanks. yes. I mean your sentence.  also I am looking for a better word or sentence . please, also is "nice welcome" good in here or not?

Comment: The sentence seems fine to me per se.
Other variants exhibiting a similar response shown by the industries to the new technology may use words like: 'readily embraced', 'godsend', 'promptly accepted', 'congruous to' , etc.

Comment: alex: "don't forget to mark it" ≠ "please mark it right away". You could (perhaps should?) wait until tomorrow; read more [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way to say this is to use [*well received*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/well-received):

> We anticipate the new technology will be **well received** by industrial companies.

That two-word expression is common enough to have gained its way into some [dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=well-received&ls=a). Moreover, it often gets used in news headlines or business reports, such as these:

> ***New Scanning Technology [Well Received](http://www.tukatech.com/content/new-scanning-technology-well-received-texprocess-0) at Texprocess***
>   ***Radar systems made in Germany [well received](http://www.radarlux.com/en/news-details/news/radar-systems-made-in-germany-well-received.html)***
>   ***Innovative products and systems [well received](http://www.incleanmag.com.au/2015/02/04/innovative-products-systems-well-received-phan-delegates/) by PHAN delegates***

When used as a two-word adjective, the expression may get a hyphen:

> ***Questek Technology Information Week: a [well-received](http://www.barco.com/en/News/Post/2014/6/13/Questek-Technology-Information-Week-a-well-received-showcase-of-Barcos-latest-product-offering) showcase of Barco’s latest product offering***

---

Of course, there are several other words or phrases that could be used, such as *become popular*, or *be attractive to*:

> We expect the new technology will **become popular** in the industrial sector.
>   We expect the new technology will **be attractive to** industrial companies.

If you don't mind using less formal language, consider:

> We expect the new technology will **be a hit** among the industrial companies.

NOAD defines the noun *hit* as, among other things, "a successful venture".